# Jquery and Ajax Data?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Nee help again with some Jquery stuff which is driving me nuts! I really hope someone can help with this.

Herewith the problem

I have 1 jquery function which runs on document.ready which gets data through a Ajax Method. I then want to use jcarousel to display the images on the page. Herewith my Script so far. Where am I going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Awards</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='ImgURL'/> \
                         </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        url: "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var ImgSrc = $(this).attr("ows_ImgURL");
        return;
    });       
}    
function StartCarousel() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({          
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Hi there. I've actually managed to fix the issue with some server side code. Thanks for the response anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue with server side code.